# Reference with constant modifier

Tags: c++, reference, constants

FirstOne::

```
double & val = 66.6;     //illegal
const double & val = 66.6;   //legal
```

I was just doing some demo programs and came through the above concept but not able to identify what exactly the need of the above concept .
what magic exactly const is doing in the second case ?

SecondOne::

```
int nVar = 12;
int &rVar = nVar ;//Ok
double &dVar = nVar ;//Error
const double &cdVar = nVar ;//Ok
```

Why the 3rd statement is not working where as 4th statement is working ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is illegal. You cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary.

The second is legal. It creates a temporary double, initialized to `66.6`, and makes `val` a const reference to it.

The `const` promises not to change the value through the reference. C++ does not permit you to bind a non-const reference to a temporary because that's usually an error.

Comment: is it  needed in real time programming ?

Comment: @viku it's needed in turn-based programming.

Comment: @viku: Is what needed in real time programming?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The above concept of using reference with constant .

Comment: I don't see any connection between references and real time programming.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what i am asking is , what all the scenario where we can use the above concept (like const double & val = 66.6;).

Comment: One case is if you want to be absolutely sure there is no copy. `const foo myFoo = bar();` might copy the returned `foo`. While `const foo& myFoo = bar();` is guaranteed to make `myFoo` reference the returned `foo` directly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks David . So if we need to avoid the copy , we have to go for reference so that program execution will be faster . is it what you are saying ?

Comment: It's not so much that execution will be faster since any decent compiler will elide the copy anyway. Consider, for example, a class that's not copyable, such as a stream.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you please see the edited post , and help me in that ?

Comment: Same reason. You can't bind a reference to a temporary. (A reference acts like the thing it refers to. It's like another name for it.)

Answer (score 3):

Let me show you.

```
void f(Base*& p) { p = new Base; }
int main() {
    Derived* d;
    f(d); // Creates temporary Base* and calls f with it
    // Dude, where's my object?
}
```

As you can see, this introduces a nasty error. Firstly, the object is leaked and cannot be recovered, as the argument to `f` does not actually refer to `d` at all. Secondly, even if `d` were successfully mutated in `f`, it would be of the wrong type and violate the type system.

Comment: While this is the reason C++ doesn't allow you to do this, it's awfully hard for a beginner to understand. (The point of the first line of code was to take in a reference to a pointer such that the pointer could be made to point to a newly-created object. But if the pointer is a temporary, then the code fails because the calling code doesn't get its pointer filled in.)

Comment: I am a beginner . Can you please explain your concept ?

Comment: Viku: The first line is a function that takes a reference so that it can make it point to a newly-created object. If that reference was a reference to a temporary, then the newly-created object would be lost when the temporary was destroyed. This is a very subtle bug. (And you could imagine even worse bugs. Consider if `f` does this: `p = new OtherClassDerivedFromBase();`. If the caller did get the pointer, a `Derived *` would point to an instance of a different class!

Answer (score 2):

Since val is a reference to another varaible, in theory this would be like in the old fortran days, were passing 1.0 to a function as a reference (whatever that method is called in fortran), and you could alter the 1.0 to something else. Some other code using 1.0 as a constant would then use the new value. It is a good idea not to allow that, I'd say.

So, the C++ standard only allows constant references to anything that you shouldn't modify - what effect do you expect if you later do `val += 4.0`? That the constant 66.6 becomes 70.6?

Edit: I take it that the scenario is that you have a function

```
void func(double &d)
{
    d += 4.0;
}
```

and you can't call it as:

```
func(66.6);
```

so you tried:

```
double &val = 66.6;
```

and that didn't work either?

The correct way to fix this is:

```
double val = 66.6;

func(val);    // compiler makes a reference to val that is passed to func.
```

Comment: Yes, I meant if the first case WAS legal, what would the expected behaviour be?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I guess it would be to create a temporary whose lifetime equals that of the reference, initialize the temporary to `66.6` and make `val` a reference to that temporary. But DeadMG's answer shows why that's not the C++ rule.

Answer (score 1):

`double & val = 66.6;`

This won't compile, you can't bind a reference to a temporary.

`const double & val = 66.6;`

This is valid and will result in a reference to the temporary `66.6`.

I don't see any reason to in declaring the value as a reference, create it as a `const double val = 66.6;` and then if later required pass it around as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

The const in the second case tells the compiler not to copy the value on the right. In your case this isn't much of a difference (the compiler will probably generate the same code).

But in the following case the result of `someFunction` is not copied but just assigned. This is particularly useful if it happens a lot or if the copy of a returned object is expensive.

```
const double & val = someFunction();
```

What you are actually doing is expanding the 'lifetime' of a value/object on the stack, instead of copying it. This is called a 'temporary'. Because of the code that created the value/object doesn't know you will be using it, you have to make it `const`.